# Why do dynamic elements under a directive have a wrong scope if added after transclusion?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider the following example, where one element is included statically into the directive definition, and other one is added later (using jQuery):

```js
angular.module('test', []).directive('transcludeThis', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div id="transcluded" data-ng-transclude></div>'
    };
}]);

$(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['test']);
  $('#transcluded').append('<div>Dynamic (jQuery): </div>').find('*').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.append(angular.element($this).scope().$id);
  });
});
```

```html
<transclude-this>
  <div>Static: </div>
</transclude-this>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
```

Why is the dynamic element not in the transcluded scope?

Answer (score 0):

Because that dynamic element did not exist when the scope for the directive was created. If you are using angular you should create your dynamic elements inside of the directive and then the scope will be maintained.